# Proving that $P(X=Y) = 0$ for any two continuous random variables

Tags: probability, formal-proofs

I have the following question to prepare for a lecture at Uni but I've been stuck on this for a long time:

> **Question**:
>
> 1. Let $Z$ and $V$ be independent with distribution $U[0,1]$. Show that $P(Z=V) = 0$.
>
>    *Hint*: Cut $[0,1]$ into intervals $A_1, \ldots , A_n$ of length $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and then used the fact that $$\{Z=V\}\subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^{2^n} \{Z\in A_i\} \cap\{V \in A_i\}$$
> 2. Using the fact that $P(Z=V) = 0$, show that $P(X=Y) = 0$ for $X$ and $Y$ being any continuous and independent random variables.

I have proved the first question, however I'm not sure how to solve the second. I know I maybe can use the fact that I can create any random distributed variable from the uniform distribution, lets say $X = F^{-1}(Z)$, but I do not know how to implement this. Any tips?

Comment: The important word is *continuous* here. Ans with your idea you are already done: If $X=F^{-1}(Z)$ and $Y=F^{-1}(W)$ then $X=Y\iff Z=W$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $X$ and $Y$ do not necessarily have the same CDF.

Comment: If X and Y are not identically distributed, I fail to see how 1. can help to prove 2. Sure about this part of the problem?

Comment: The title says $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., so I suppose we have that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.

Comment: That is a typo in the title actually. There is nothing in my assignment that says that X and Y are iid.

Comment: What definition of continuous random variable do you use? If you allow arbitrary probability distributions you could still have $P(Z=V)$ being nonzero, fx if you have set $P(Z=a)>0$ for some $a$.

Comment: @skyking Please do not divert the discussion: no sensible definition of *continuous* random variable Z allows P(Z=z)>0 for some z.

Comment: @Did Googling for it I came up fx with the following: "A continuous random variable is a random variable where the data can take infinitely many values. For example, a random variable measuring the time taken for something to be done is continuous since there are an infinite number of possible times that can be taken.". Such a definition would not do. Otherwise depending on the definition it would be more or less easy to do some assumption about the variable.

Comment: The "tips" from my teacher was that I could produce arbitrary random variables from unifroms (as I mentioned) and the inverse the cdfs. Not how that helps...

Comment: @skyking This is most basic but here we go: A continuous random variable is such that the data takes infinitely many values. A random variable such that the data takes infinitely many values is not necessarily continuous.

Answer (score 2):

By Fubini,
\begin{gather}
P(X = Y) = E[\mathbf 1_{X=Y}]= \iint_{\mathbb R^2} \mathbf 1_{x=y} F_X(dx) F_Y(dy) = \int_{\mathbb R} E[\mathbf 1_{X=y}] F_Y(dy)\\ = \int_{\mathbb R} P(X=y) F_Y(dy) = 0
\end{gather}
(the inner probability is zero in view of continuity of $X$). Note that $Y$ does not need to be continuous.

Comment: It's not clear where and how you use the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This is an important property since it's obviously not tru if they are dependent - eg. if actually $X=Y$.

Comment: @skyking, $F_{(X,Y)} (dx,dy) = F_X(dx)F_Y(dy)$.

Comment: That is indeed a solid proof. But it is not using $P(Z=V)=0$ for iid $Z,V$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. So it does not really answer the question.

Comment: @drhab, you are right. However, I see no way to show this *using* that $P(Z=V)=0$ for independent $Z,V\simeq U[0,1]$ unless $X$ and $Y$ have identical distribution (which was discussed in the comments to the original question).

Comment: @zhoraster The proof is good but as this is a assignment to hand in I cannot really answer the question with this type of answer.